# Add field to App Engine-hosted database

Tags: database, web-services, google-app-engine, datastore, gql

I'm currently developing a mobile application who uses a Google App Engine-hosted web service.

But i'm facing an issue. I just want to add a field in one my database's table.
App Engine doesn't use classic SQL syntax, but GQL. So i cannot use the ALTER TABLE statement. How can i do this with GQL ? I looked for a solution on the web, but there's not a lot of help.

```
public MyEntity() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key idStation;
private String name;
private double longitude;
private double latitude;
private java.util.Date dateRefresh = new Date(); //the field i want to add in DB
```

So, now when i create a "MyEntity" object, it should add the "dateRefresh" field into the database... I create my object like this:

```
MyEntity station = new MyEntity();
station.setName("test");
station.setLatitude(0);
station.setLongitude(0);
station.setDateRefresh(new Date("01/01/1980"));

DaoFactory.getStationDao().addStation(station);
```

addStation method:

```
@Override
public MyEntity addStation(MyEntity station) {
    EntityManager em = PersistenceManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    try {           
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(station);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        if(em.getTransaction().isActive()) em.getTransaction().rollback();
        em.close();
    }
    return station;
}
```

The field "dateRefresh" is never created into my DB...

Someone to help me please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Just add another field to your data structure, maybe providing a `default` clause, and that's all. For example, if you have a `UserAccount`:

```
class UserAccount(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty()
    user_id = db.StringProperty()
```

you may easily add:

```
class UserAccount(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty()
    user_id = db.StringProperty()
    extra_info = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    timezone = db.StringProperty(default="UTC")
```

and let it go.

Comment: Can you give me more details about this please ? Is that a Python script to upload on App Engine ? I'm using JPA and EntityManager JAVA objects...

Comment: it's same with Java, just add the fields you need and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

While the datastore kinda mimics tables, data is stored on a per entity basis.  There is no schema or table.

All you need to do is update your model class, and new entities will be saved with the structure (fields) of the new entity.

Old entities and indexes, however, are not automatically updated.  They still have the same fields as they had when they were originally written to the datastore.

There's two ways to do this.  One is to make sure your code can handle situations where your new properties are missing, ie make sure no exceptions are thrown, or handle the exceptions properly when you're missing the properties.

The second way is to write a little function (usu a mapreduce function) to update every entity with appropriate or null values for your new properties.

Note that indexes are not updated unless the entity is written.  So if you add a new indexed property, old entities won't show up when you query for the new property.  In this case, you must use the second method and update all the entities in the datastore so that they are indexed.

Comment: Thanks.

That's what i had understood. So, i added the field to my entity (java class), and i tried to instantiate an object from this entity. But, when i try to persist this object in the database, it fails because the field isn't present in the database.

However, when i debug my web service locally, the new field is present and its value for the old entities is null... But when i deploy my web service on App Engine, the field isn't on the database.

Thanks

Comment: You're using the HRD right (you must be, I don't think GQL works on CloudSQL)?  You might want to show your actual code and errors that you're getting.  You may be misinterpretting the error, since you shouldn't see a problem on write if you're adding a new property, provided that the new property is added to the model.

Comment: Add your code and error message to the question, otherwise, people can't help you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Java API.  First I'm not sure you need to assign a new Date() object in the declaration.  Second, I'd investigate station.setDateRefresh(new Date("01/01/1980")); and check whether that is actually setting the date properly.  Otherwise, it doesn't look very wrong.